# When I am trying to send image from system it is not showing in mail body

Tags: asp.net

This is my code:

```
{

            string To = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["userInfo"]["Email"]).ToString();
            string name = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["userInfo"]["Name"]).ToString();

            string Subject = "IQC Non-leather Status";
            
            string email_body = "Item has been checked by QC with the following details.. ";

            string sImage = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/image.jpg");



            DataTable dtqc = new ifs_ShipmentInfo_DAL().qc_po_info(site, IQC_STORE_SL);

            email_body += @"<table>";

            if (dtqc.Rows.Count > 0)
```

This is the mail body:

```
            {
                DataRow dr = dtqc.Rows[0];
                email_body += "<tr><td>Supplier Name</td><td>:</td><td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["SUPPLIER_NAME"]) + "</td></tr>";
                email_body += "<tr><td>PO NO</td><td>:</td><td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["PO_NO"]) + "</td></tr>";
                email_body += "<tr><td>Invoice No</td><td>:</td><td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["COMMERCIAL_INV_NO"]) + "</td></tr>";
                email_body += "<tr><td>Invoice recvd date</td><td>:</td><td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["DATE_OF_RECEIVING"]) + "</td></tr>";
                email_body += "<tr><td>Part No</td><td>:</td><td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["PART_NO"]) + "</td></tr>";
                email_body += "<tr><td>Part Description</td><td>:</td><td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["PART_DESC"]) + "</td></tr>";
                email_body += "<tr><td>Invoice Qnty</td><td>:</td><td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["INVOICE_QTY"]) + "</td></tr>";
                email_body += "<tr><td>Final Result</td><td>:</td><td>" + INSPECTION_RESULT + "</td></tr>";
                email_body += "<tr><td>Reason</td><td>:</td><td>" + insRemarks + "</td></tr>"
                       + "<tr><td>Inspected Qnty</td><td>:</td><td>" + INSPECTION_QTY + "</td></tr>"
                       + "<tr><td>Accepted Qnty</td><td>:</td><td>" + ACCEPTED_QTY + "</td></tr>"
                       + "<tr><td>Rejected Qnty</td><td>:</td><td>" + REJECTED_QTY + "</td></tr>"
                       + "<tr><td>Fully Rejected Qnty</td><td>:</td><td>" + FINAL_REJECTED_QTY + "</td></tr>"
                       + "<tr><td>Inspected By</td><td>:</td><td>" + INSPECTED_BY + "</td></tr>"
```

Trying to send image like this:

```
                        + "<tr><td>Defective Picture</td><td>:</td><td><img src='" + sImage + "'width='100'height='100'alt='img'style='margin:20px 0px 0px 20px'/></td></tr>";
            }

            email_body += "</table>";
```

Comment: What path do you see assigned to `sImage` variable?

Comment: string sImage = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/image.jpg");

Comment: That's the code... You need to debug the code and see the value which is assigned to `sImage` variable. I belive that will be local path of the image like `C:\applicationpath\...`. the local path will not work when the email will be rendered... the `src` of the image should be the URL which is publicly accessible. So `sImage` should have value like `https://<<applicationdomain>>/Content/Uploads/image.jpg`

Comment: You can do something like following...`var requestURL = HttpContext.Current.Request;; var sImage = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", requestURL.Url.Scheme, requestURL.Url.Authority, "Content/Uploads/image.jpg");`